# Unity3d(Editor): Opening Multiple files using EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I was watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vh_XkNwThg4) and did complete it, now I want to extend it.

I want to open multiple images using FileExplorer in unity and then able to show the images based on the slider's value as seen in this image:

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Using the EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel(), you can only open a file at a time, but u can use this https://forum.unity.com/threads/standalone-file-browser.451631/ and for changing images just create a list and have the opened images in it, when the value of the slider changes, just set the Raw Image's sprite to that of the image in the list by using an int to get the image from the list. Hope this helps, ik i made it a bit confusing in the end.

Comment: A duplicate of one of the Unity Answers questions: https://answers.unity.com/questions/667903/editorutilityopenfilepanel-select-multiple-files-3.html

Comment: @user8 it is actually only called/markable as a "duplicate" if a question/answer exists here on StackOverflow ;)

Comment: What about however selecting a folder and open all files from that folder? At least a little workaround ;)

Comment: @derHugo I like your idea. Can you give me a hand with the slider?

Comment: I don't know what your slider is supposed to do .. especially with multiple files

Comment: @derHugo Yes, I am aware of that. Still it is a "duplicate" and does give additional information.

Comment: @착한어른이 you might want to vote for it [here](https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/editorutility-dot-openfilepanel-should-have-an-alternative-with-multiple-file-selection)

Comment: @derHugo Can you give me a little code for "just create a list and have the opened images in it, when the value of the slider changes, just set the Raw Image's sprite to that of the image in the list by using an int to get the image from the list. "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't answer the question but what you asked in the comments

> Can you give me a little code for "just create a list and have the opened images in it, when the value of the slider changes, just set the Raw Image's sprite to that of the image in the list by using an int to get the image from the list."?

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(RawImage))]
public class ImageSwitcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    private RawImage image;

    public Slider SliderComponent;

    // Get the textures somehow
    public List<Texture>() textures = new List<Texture>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        image = GetComponent<RawImage>();

        if(!SliderComponent)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No SliderComponent referenced!", this);
            return;
        }

        // Make the slider accept only whole numbers
        SliderComponent.wholeNumbers = true;

        SliderComponent.value = 0;

        SliderComponent.minValue = 0;

        // Index is 0 based so can maximal be list count -1
        SliderComponent.maxValue = textures.Count - 1;

        // Register a listener for onValueChanged
        // Remove the listener first to avoid multiple listeners added
        SliderComponent.onValueChanged.RemoveListener(OnSliderChanged);
        SliderComponent.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnSliderChanged);
    }

    private void OnDestroy ()
    {
        // Always clean up listeners when not needed anymore
        SliderComponent.onValueChanged.RemoveListener(OnSliderChanged);
    }

    // Use this to change the Texture list
    // and Max value of the slider afterwards
    public void UpdateSlider(List<Texture> textures)
    {
        // Update the texture list
        this.textures = textures;

        // Update the max value of the slider
        SliderComponent.maxValue = textures.Count - 1;

        // Unity might automatically clamp the slider value
        // after the maxValue was changed
        // But just to be sure we can do it as well
        SliderComponent.value = Mathf.Clamp(SliderComponent.value, 0, textures.Count - 1);
    }


    // Called when the slider value is changed
    private void OnSliderChanged()
    {
        // Get the value as int
        int index = Mathf.RoundToInt(SliderComponent.value);

        if(index < 0 || index > textures.Count - 1)
        {
            // Should actually be impossible but just in case log it
            Debug.Log("Slider produced impossible index: " + index, this);
            return;
        }

        // Get according texture from list
        var texture = textures[index];

        // Set texture
        image.texture = texture;
    }
}
```

---

However this doesn't completely solve your question

> Unity3d(Editor): Opening Multiple files using EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel()

as mentioned in [this thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/667903/editorutilityopenfilepanel-select-multiple-files-3.html) it is not possible since [`EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel.html) returns only one single filepath as `string`.

So short answer would be: **It's (currently) not possible**.

There is an open [vote](https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/editorutility-dot-openfilepanel-should-have-an-alternative-with-multiple-file-selection) for adding that functionality for multiple selections so you might want to vote there.

One idea of mine would be to try to select a folder path instead and load all textures from that folder but that is only a workaround and not really what you requested.

But I hope the rest helps you a bit :)